# tail | grep -q always returning true

Tags: shell

When I execute this code, the loop always ends at first time (even when the last two lines of `auth.log` doen't contain "exit"), which means that `$c` always gets some string:

```
while true;
do
    c=$(tail -2 /var/log/auth.log | grep -q "exit")
    if $c ;
    then
            echo "true"
            unset c
            break
    fi
```

done

Do you know why `c=$(tail -2 /var/log/auth.log | grep -q "exit")` is always getting some kind of string? I think it is becaues of `tail`.

I can use the `-o` option and then compare strings, but I prefer to use a boolean inside the `if` condition.

Comment: I mean the output of grep -q can just be "true" (0) ( if there is some string matching "exit") or (false) (1) if its empty, but it seems $c have some string when tere is no "exit" in last 2 lines if auth.log

Comment: Try this to understand: `unset c; if $c; then echo "Evaluated to true"; fi`

Comment: if i try this it jumps to the loop

Comment: The point was that if you use an unset parameter as the condition, it always evaluates to true. The test to see if a parameter equals the empty string would be `[ -z "$c" ]` (or `[ -n "$c" ]` to test if it is *not* the empty string), but the main problem is answered in mklement0's answer.

Comment: Thanks guy now it works like a charm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`grep -q` by design returns no *output*, it simply signals via its *exit code* whether a match was found.

Thus, you can simply use your pipeline *directly* as a condition:

```
while true;
do
    if tail -2 /var/log/auth.log | grep -q "exit";
    then
            echo "true"
            break
    fi
done
```

---

As for what you tried:

As [Benjamin W.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3266847/benjamin-w) implies in a comment on the question, executing a *command* expanding to the *empty string* is always considered a *successful* command.

<sup>Note: Whether the command is effectively empty because the variable in question is *unset* or, as in this case, was explicitly assigned a null (empty) string, doesn't matter.</sup>

Thus, given that `$c` is invariably empty - because `grep -q` by design never returns stdout output - the `if` condition always evaluates to true.

To be clear: `$c`, since it is *not* being used in a *conditional* (`if $c; ...` rather than `if [ "$c" ]; ...`), is interpreted as a *command to execute* rather than as a *string to test for emptiness*.

*If* the command whose output is captured in `$c` were to generate stdout output, you'd have to test for that with a *conditional*: `if [ -n "$c" ]; then ...` (or, more succinctly, `if [ "$c" ]; then ...`).

Comment: So in my old code I was evaluating the empty variable $c , and when I use grep -q there is no output and then the variable c takes his default "" what is something, so if I try to evaluate it it will be always a true.And the if has to evaluate the command not the variable (output)

Comment: @hakimoto: Yes, a variable _executed as a command_ always indicates true if it is empty. I guess the logic is: if there's no command, then it doesn't fail, so the exit code is not set to a nonzero value. Note that conditionals (and therefore `if` statements) only operate based on _exit codes_, irrespective of any stdout (or stderr) output. Again, if you evaluated `$c` _inside a conditional_ (`[ "$c" ]`) then the logic would _reverse_, because the value is tested for emptiness: an empty value then signals false.